# Play an audio file when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so when you click a button, it echo's out a person's name from an ajax to a php array & then plays the song of there choice.

Here is what I've got at the moment;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/ajax.php"
        }).done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            $(".person").html(msg);
            if (msg == "name") { 
                $('a.click').append("<audio class='audio' src='includes/songs/song.mp3' autoplay></audio>");
            } else {
                $('audio').remove();
            }
        });   
    });
});
```

This does work but that would mean I would have to have 10 different `if` statements, which I don't want to do.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need 10 different `if` statements? It also seems a little redundant to make the same AJAX call on every click. Make the call once and cache the result

Comment: Because there are more 10 people in the list, it selects a random person from an array & echo's out the name.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't make sense as you're making the same request every time. How does it know which name to show?

Comment: You could build an `Object` with your possible values of `msg` as keys and your possible values of the audio `src` as values, and then iterate through it. Or even better, you could treat this directly in your `ajax.php` page and output the result as a JSON, then parse it in your JS call.

Comment: Make a dynamic link??

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a dynamic link:

```
$().append("<audio src='/songs/"+msg+".mp3'>");
```

Or you could resolve the audio using a database and pass the dynamic url back to the client, or you could create an object storing the data:

```
var songof={
tim:"/songs/a.mp3",
bob:...
}
```

And than do:

```
url=songof[msg];
```

Or you could resolve the song dynamically (you have to be good in php)

```
 <audio src="resolvesong.php?tim">
```

PS: What happens if one person is clicked twice? Than the songs would be downloaded and added multiple times. So it would be a good idea to store the downloaded songs:

```
var songof={};
newsong=document.createElement("audio");
newsong.src="url.mp4";
document.body.appendChild(newsong);
songof["tim"]=newsong;
```

To play do

```
songof["tim"].play();
```